# Conflict between mod_rewrite and CSRF check

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, csrf

I'm developing an app, with CSRF and mod_rewrite, but I have some problems with it. Everything works good on Safari and Firefox, but on Chrome the login doesn't work, and it's because of one line of my .htaccess code.

That line:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+)+[^\.php]$ profile.php?user=$0 [QSA,L]
```

I've a CSRF token that is stored in a session everytime you visit a page. The problem is I think that the .htaccess file loads the page twice, so the CSRF token changes before the post data arrives and it doesn't validate the submit.

Obviously, when I delete the line on the .htaccess file, it works on Chrome.

Can anybody help me? Please.

This is the code of my .htaccess file:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !PHPSESSID= [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+)+[^\.php]$ profile.php?user=$0 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 400 /errors/badrequest.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/authreqd.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbid.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/serverr.php
```

Comment: If loading the page twice is the problem, that rewritr rule isn't the cause. Check for 404s such as `jquery.min.map`.

Comment: Yes, because when I delete the RewriteUrl line of "profile.php?user=$0", everything works.

Comment: Note that `[^\.php]` means “any character except `.`, `p`, and `h`” but not “not `.php`”.

Comment: So, what does it mean? What I have to change?

Comment: @EnricEnrich that's because it captures any request that is not a file and does not end with . p or h . Your rewrite rule is capturing more than you think, that's not the same thing as "loading the page twice" hence I say to check for 404s.

Comment: @AD7six So, what I have to do? What I have to change?